# What is '---Transition from client to server---'?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

On attaching to w3wp.exe and running my application, I get a particular line in my call stack.
Please see the image:
[image]

I wanted to know the significance on the line highlighted in blue.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are in 2 different stack "context".  I reproduce your problem by calling a Web service.  I get 1 stack for my client (web application) and one stack for my service.

In your case, your debugger is not attach on the external process.

Here a print screen of it.(sorry it is in french)

[image: Transition from client to server]

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to SoapServerMessage as explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/0aa3e4ca-5396-4158-b62b-a6e048773f31)